# Print the first side of the web view different

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

I'm working with Swift 4 for macOS and I can load a HTML string into my web view and print this with my code:

```
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
printInfo.orientation = .portrait
printInfo.topMargin = 0
printInfo.rightMargin = 0
printInfo.bottomMargin = 50
printInfo.leftMargin = 0
printInfo.verticalPagination = .autoPagination

let printOp = NSPrintOperation(view: sender.mainFrame.frameView.documentView, printInfo: printInfo)

printOp.run()
```

Is it possible to apply different `printInfo` settings only for the first page?

For example: The first page should have `topMargin = 50` and all other pages should have `0`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set those values for the **whole document** and not for individual pages. If you want to set up different margins for a specific page, you'll have to modify the document directly.